# compare to sum of 2 text box values

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, controls

I am learning c#. I am building a web app that calculates slugging stats. To make sure that the at bats is greater than or equal to all the hits, I needed to compare the value of at bats to the sum value of singles, doubles, triples, and homeruns.
I am comparing using this validator.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtAtBats"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:CompareValidator ID="validateAllHitsCompareAtBats" runat="server" 
        ErrorMessage="The at bat needs to be greater than total hits." Operator="GreaterThanEqual" Display="Dynamic" 
        ControlToValidate="txtAtBats" ></asp:CompareValidator>
```

These are my textboxes:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtSingles"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtDoubles"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtTriples"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtHomeRuns"></asp:TextBox>
```

My question is how do I group the values of these 4 textboxes and compare it to the value of the atbat textbox by using the comparevalidator.

Comment: What is the specific question?

Comment: What's the behavior? do you want to post the page and check on Server-side or do a Client-side validation?

Comment: I want to use the .net client side validator

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: oh sorry. I didn't mean to add a tag in the title

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm not an asp developer but I believe you're looking for something like this;

```
public bool validateAllHitsCompareAtBats()
{
     int hits = int.Parse(txtSingles.Text) + int.Parse(txtDoubles.Text) + int.Parse(txtTriples.Text) + int.Parse(txtHomeRuns.Text);

     return int.Parse(txtAtBats.Text) >= hits;
}
```

I'm not sure my logic to access the values in the textboxes is correct because I do not write ASP code but on the back end that is the basic logic you want; take the sum of each hit type then check that the total at bats is greater than or equal to them.

Since you didn't post any C# code I don't have much to go off of... You should do that next time. You're looking for a solution in C#, the HTML isn't relevant, I'm only using it to make inferences about what your C# might look like.

Answer (score 0):

firstly insert Compare Validator in front of the textbox of which value you want to compare(as Confirm Password,as when u wants to compare it with Password field)
then in Properties (by F4) fill the "control to validate" and "control to compare" 
that is it.

Comment: The question is how to compare value of one control with values from several (more than one) controls. Your answer doesn't seem to cover this case